# Indefinite integral $\int x^{7/2}\sqrt{\ln x}e^x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can we , somehow, evaluate the integral:
$$\int x^{7/2}\sqrt{\ln x}e^x\,dx$$
I don't see a starting point.

**Edit:** The original integral was re-written in its simplified expression.

Comment: It is quite an hard task to "evaluate" an indefinite integral :) Please put it in the simplified version: $$\int x^{7/2}\sqrt{\log x}\,e^x\,dx.$$

Comment: Why do you think it has a closed form? And did you forget to add limits?

Comment: Because the proposer of this integral says he has a solution, that he refuses to publish.! That is why I think it has a closed form.

Comment: Where/Who is the proposer?

Comment: I don't know the name of the proposer.. (it was in a conference) he/she  was anonymous... you see.. that is what makes me angry.. and this integral is a bone in my throat for three months.

Comment: I don't think this integral have a closed form and any limits won't make it much "evaluatably".

Comment: @Tolaso I imagine the mysterious proposer say that he discovered a truly marvelous antiderivative, which margin of the conference program is too narrow to contain...

Comment: Let me show you what i've tried: First I applied the sub $u=\ln x$ got nowhere because $dx=e^u\, du$ which is just perfect. Applying $x=e^u$ on the initial integral , I get a very complicated one.. That $e^x$ term does not stand me very well...

Comment: @CuriousGuest If he did then I'd like to see that antiderivative of his. It would be nice. But the terms don't seem to match together..

Comment: General advice for "integral of a product" is: integrate by parts.  If you don't get anywhere with that method, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: @GEdgar  My friend I have tried that after the sub method failed... I applied PARTS with $e^x$ and then differentiated the other two terms.. I guess I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

**This is NOT an answer to the question**

To illustrate the complexity (probably induced by the $\sqrt{\log(x)}$ term), let me consider a much simpler case

$$I=\int x^{7/2}~~{\ln( x)}~~e^x\,dx$$ for which the result is 
$$1296 I =81 \left(105 \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)+2 e^x \sqrt{x}
   \left(8 x^3-28 x^2+70 x-105\right)\right) \log (x)-$$ $$ 64 x^{9/2} \,
   _2F_2\left(\frac{9}{2},\frac{9}{2};\frac{11}{2},\frac{11}{2};x\right)$$ If I had time, I suppose that playing with the coefficients of similar nightmares, I could find $a$ $truly$ $marvelous$ $antiderivative$ (quoting CuriousGuest).

Comment: Well, as I said before these terms simply do not match with one another. Either applying IBP or subs (of whatever kind) that I've done... I get no result.... I have not tried any limits of integrations , but I suppose I will have no luck as well.